# Compiling a file in java

Tags: java, cmd

I've been searching the internet for about a week, including copying YouTube tutorials letter by letter. I've just started using java, and my computer refuses to compile and then run any code I give to it. does anyone have any suggestions? I think there could be a problem with my computer e.g. I've added or removed a file I shouldn't have. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. the file name I'm using is 'Hello World  and its in notepad

tried typing up code in both types of notepad (ones that have the logo as a whole notepad, and ones that have a single paper as a logo) and I've tried numerous lines of code in CMD

*in notepad*

```
public class Hello World
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

*in cmd*

```
javac Hello World

javac Hello World.java

javac Hello World.class

javac Hello World.txt

javac HelloWorld.java etc.
```

these are some of the commands ive tried in cmd

I expect 'hello world' to be printed, instead I get:

command: javac Hello World.class

```
error: invalid flag: World.class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

command:javac Hello World.txt

```
error: Class names, 'Hello,World.txt', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
```

Command:javac Hello World.java

```
error: file not found: Hello,World.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: So, what's the current working directory in your `cmd` process, and where is the file `HelloWorld.java` stored? If those are different directories, you have to make adjustments.

Comment: "in notepad" if you're struggling this much, please, try to use an IDE. It's not cheating.

Comment: @Dirk that's the cd command right?

Comment: @AndyTurner didn't realise you could use and IDE, thaks

Comment: ["Hello World!" for Microsoft Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html)

Comment: The problem is that your class name is `Hello World`. This is definitely a syntax error. Class names cannot have space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a space in a class name:

```
public class HelloWorld
```

Because this is public, it needs to be in a file called `HelloWorld.java`.

Then compile with `javac HelloWorld.java`, and run with `java HelloWorld`.

Comment: that gives me the error error:                 file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

Comment: Change directory to the file containing `HelloWorld.java`.

Comment: @BigdaddyRudolf4567 rename the file to HelloWorld.java

Answer (score 0):

No spaces are allowed in class names. Hence, remove the space from class name and file name.

Now go to the directory you created the java file in. e.g. `cd ~/Docuements/projects`

There run following one by one:

```
javac HelloWorld.java

java HelloWorld
```